# Limitation for Transpose Function

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to find a workaround as transpose will not fit my data size, which is giving me an error. What do I added in right before the end of the loop -before the Next- to paste the data on a new sheet? Will this slow down the macro it the output is 100,000 lines

After reviewing the code I realized that if I make the range to a certain number it works and +1 row after that it errors out. Turns out transpose is to blame.

```
  For Q = 1 To Data + 1

                n = n + 1

                ReDim Preserve var(1 To 3, 1 To n)
                var(1, n) = 

                For R = 2 To 6
                    var(r, n) = 
                Next R
                var(1, n) = 
                var(2, n) = 
            Next Q

Next_Loop:
        Next P

        With this workbook.sheet1
            If Q>= 2 Then
               .Range("a1").Resize(n, 6) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(var)
            End If
```

The result should be instead of pasting all the data at the end, it pastes the data after each iteration (unless it slows down the macro). Next iteration would be below the previous line of data. etc.

thank you for any insight

Comment: Make the array a 2d Array `Dim var(1 to x, 1 to 1)` where x is the number of rows desired.  Then you can avoid the use of transpose.

Comment: there are 16,384 columns, so you can't transpose more than that https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

Comment: Create a function to return a transposed version of `var` - just need to size a new array and use a nested loop to copy over the values.

Comment: Please show us how `var` is allocated (i.e. the `ReDim` statement, or the assignments `var = Range().Resize().Value`)

Comment: Hello, I update the code block but I think I need to make a privet sub to fix the issue. Not sure how to write that.

Comment: Is this code a UDF (user defined function)? Please post more _relevent_ code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option for you to try.

```
Sub LongColumnToAFewColumns()
    Dim wsF As Worksheet, WST As Worksheet
    Dim rf As Range, rT As Range
    Dim R As Long, j As Integer

    ' initialize
    Set wsF = ActiveSheet
    Set WST = Sheets.Add
    WST.Name = "Results"

    j = 1

    For R = 1 To wsF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step 65536
        wsF.Cells(R, 1).Resize(65536).Copy
        WST.Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

WST.Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        j = j + 1
    Next R

End Sub
```

If you want one long column cut into a few long rows, then use this.

```
Sub LongColumnToAFewRows()
    Dim wsF As Worksheet, WST As Worksheet
    Dim rf As Range, rT As Range
    Dim R As Long, j As Integer

    ' initialize
    Set wsF = ActiveSheet
    Set WST = Sheets.Add
    WST.Name = "Results2"

    j = 1

    For R = 1 To wsF.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row Step Columns.Count
        wsF.Cells(R, 1).Resize(Columns.Count).Copy
        WST.Cells(j, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Transpose:=True
        j = j + 1
    Next R

End Sub
```

One more for consideration.

```
Sub testing()
 Dim wsSource As Worksheet
 Dim wsDest As Worksheet
 Dim ptrSource As Long
 Dim ptrDest As Long
 Dim colDest As Long

    Set wsDest = Sheets.Add
    wsDest.Name = "Results"
    Set wsSource = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    colDest = 1
    ptrSource = 1
    ptrDest = 1
    Do While Len(wsSource.Cells(ptrSource, 1)) > 0
        wsDest.Cells(ptrDest, colDest) = wsSource.Cells(ptrSource, 1)
            If colDest = Columns.Count Then
                colDest = 0
                ptrDest = ptrDest + 1
            End If
        ptrSource = ptrSource + 1
        colDest = colDest + 1
    Loop
    Set wsDest = Nothing
    Set wsSource = Nothing

End Sub
```